# Bizarre results with classification models

Tags: classification, logistic-regression, ensemble-learning, catboost

I am running a few classification models like logistic regression and catboosting. I have taken away part of the train set as unseen data .
When I train both on train and unseen data and get the metrics using log regression I am getting all the metrics like accuracy , AUC,F1,Recall all greater than 0.90. As it's a class imbalance problem i have even balanced the classes using smote .And also I have used z score to normalise all variables
Where the model performs well on train and unseen data and on test data , when I actually run on the set of data ( unlabelled) which I want to predict model is only giving me 10 1s. And rest 150k 0s
Could there be really an issue with my model or it is indeed the way the data is ?

Comment: Please avoid using words like *lakh* that are not globally understood

Comment: yes I have corrected